# How to check if an encrypted data file has only headers inside it and no data?

Tags: shell-script

I am managing a server which acts as a landing server between a source and a target.

We receive encrypted files and sometimes, the encrypted files will have only the Headers and contain no actual data.

This, along with the fact that it is encrypted adds some bytes to the file.
Also, I wont be able to decrypt the file.

I am a noob to UNIX and could you please suggest some techniques to ***find out if the file that has been received is a data-empty file or not***?

All suggestions are welcome..

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please indicate what encryption method is commonly used in the installation you are managing, and what platform specifically (UNIX, BSD, Linux, ideally with version) the server is running on. Some of that information can have serious impact on how a solution to the problem might look like.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't decrypt it and check? Also, will the headers always be the same? Will the encryption method and encryption key always be the same? Would checking the file's md5sum be enough, for example?

Comment: The platform is UNIX and the encryption used is gpg. Also, we cannot decrypt the file as the decryption key will be installed on the target server. The headers will be the same for files of similar pattern